# Не делается резиновый фон

Tags: html, css

Поставил background-size, но он не сработал.

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div{
    display:block;
}

body{
    background-size: 100% 100%; 
   background:url(images/bg.png);
}
header {
    height:8%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.right{
float:left;
    background-color: #fff;
    width:15%;
    height:100%;
    }
.menu{float:left;
    background-color:#fff;
width:70%;
height:100%;
 }
.left{float:left;
    background-color: #fff;
    width:15%;
    height:100%;

}
img{
border:none;
}

ul{
    margin-left:10%;
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#fff;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li {
    float: left;
    height: 90%;
    width:10%;
    background-color:#fff; text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;

}

a { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
}
.container{

}
```

Comment: Создайте более подробный вопрос, приведите пример.

Answer (score 6):

Поставьте `background-size` после  `background`

```
body {

   background:url(images/bg.png);

   background-size: 100% 100%; 
}
```

Comment: Никогда бы не подумал, что порядок написания кода, тоже играет свою роль. Большое спасибо!

Comment: @V.Clerk, еще как играет!

Comment: @V.Clerk, ну так `background` — это групповое свойство, задающее всё одним махом. Всё, что в нём не указано, сбрасывается в значения по умолчанию.

Answer (score 2):

Резиновый фон лучше не использовать, это решение подходит только для фиксированной версткой, и когда картинка имеет соотношение такое же, как монитор пользователя.

***Пример***:

```css
html { 
  background: url(http://www.shareable.net/sites/default/files/blog/top-image/city%20pic.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

ps. Решил немного дополнить. Просто изначально лучше не использовать данный подход.  Решение выше кроссбраузерное, так что можно смело использовать.